# Keycloak Admin API - Custom user id when creating user and assigning multiple users to a role

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

I have 2 questions regarding Keycloak Admin API:

1) Is it currently possible to assign a custom user ID when creating a user via Keycloak admin API? I know it is not possible a few years back.

2) I am able to assign multiple realm roles to a user using Keycloak Admin API, is it possible for the reverse way? I can't seem to find an API that allows me to assign multiple users to a realm role.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Keycloak 9.0.0, as far as I can see,

1) No. User ID is auto generated even if it is given.
2) No. You need to send multiple assign requests.

Comment: Could you please provide a link to where that's is stated or proof is? I don't find a way to do it, tho also don't find anything official that really says that i definitely can't do it.